# Assembly Binding Warning

Tags: .net, binding, versioning

I copied over my project to another PC. I have a reference to a assembly on my project.
On this new PC, a higher version of this referenced assembly exists. I keep getting a warning each time I compile. The warning is along these lines.

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1360,9): warning MSB3247: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly.
```

I deleted the reference to my OLD file and added a reference to the higher version. The warning continues to stay. Is there some way I can get rid of the warning completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try to install a newer version on the "first" PC with the original project? But perhaps that just creates the same problem there though.. Perhaps this can help: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxcompact/thread/73d1b418-0b2d-4649-b491-21b39a468457

Comment: Thanks for the link. It is a bit dated, but I have fixed the issue by adding a binding reference in my app.config file. A file that I didn't have prior to this.